# How to use sapply function on specific columns?

Tags: r, sapply

I have a function that removes columns without a given number of unique values. This command does it for the whole data frame. How would I do this on specific columns? Say columns 3 to 50? Thanks.

```
ms_10 <- ms_10[, sapply(ms_10, function(col) length(unique(col))) > 440]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset the data first and then apply the same function.

```
new_data <- ms_10[3:50]
new_data <- new_data[, sapply(new_data, function(col) length(unique(col))) > 440]
```

If you don't want to create temporary variable (`new_data`).

```
ms_10[3:50][, sapply(ms_10[3:50], function(col) length(unique(col))) > 440]
```

---

We can also use `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

ms_10 %>%
  select(3:50) %>%
  select(where(~n_distinct(.) > 440))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it whilst keeping columns 1 and 2 in the df? I want the function to be applied to 3:50 but still want to keep columns 1 and 2.

Comment: You can `cbind` the first 2 columns to the output of above. `cbind(ms_10[1:2], new_data)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
Filter(function(x) length(unique(x)) > 440, ms_10[3:50])
```